# "SaveAs" places file in a folder one level higher than expected

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to save my file with a name as the value in range("A3") in sheets(2) into one of my folders called "my assignment".

It does not save into folder instead it saves it on my desktop.

`\\fab2crp-nas1\home22\kkang2\Profile\Desktop\my assignment` refers to folder directory where I want to save it.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="\\fab2crp-nas1\home22\kkang2\Profile\Desktop\my assignment" & _
  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A3").Value & "_Jramp" & ".xlsm", FileFormat:= _
   xlNormal, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False _
   , CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: Assuming your file name in the cell doesn't start with `\ ` so add that at the end of your hard coded file path: `"\\fab2crp-nas1\home22\kkang2\Profile\Desktop\my assignment\"`

Comment: @Dean ah i see, i didn't really know the additional \ at the end of the directory could make so much of a difference. Actually what is the rationale behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your file name in the cell doesn't start with `\` so add that at the end of your hard coded file path: `"\\fab2crp-nas1\home22\kkang2\Profile\Desktop\my assignment\"`.

The reason for this is because the last `\` specifies the folder for the file to be stored in. I am not too sure on the specifics, but I am sure you can read up more on this in your OS documents.

To give an example:

If I have a file called `Book1.xlsx` and it is stored in a folder on the Desktop called `Example` then if I open the properties of that file to see its folder location I get the below:

[image]

So to continue on with this, in order for the program to locate/ access/ store your file, you would need to explicitly define the address. In my example:

`C:\Users\deadevil\Desktop\Example\Book1.xlsx`

Hope this helps clarify.